# valor ID autoincremental

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo una duda respecto a los valores AUTOINCREMENT en MySQL

En un sistema que estoy desarrollando te permite guardar proyectos y los correspondientes papeleos que debe llevar (constancias, cartas, planillas), en la ventana de registro te pide ingresar un codigo, que sera el ID, yo en mi tabla de proyectos le tengo el valor autoincremental.

Pero que ocurre, el codigo que tengo para guardar el proyecto lee el valor que esta en la caja de texto proy_id, y luego hace el guardado, si dejaba esa casilla vacía en la base de datos si guardaba el registro como id:1, id:2, id:3, pero no guardaba el papeleo porque no encontraba a que ID de proyecto guardar.

Mi pregunta es como puedo hacer para que en código aparezca un valor automático, si es posible el que sera guardado en la base de datos, que salga 1 , 2 , 3 , 4, 5

```
    <input type="text" maxlength="5"  class="form-control" name="proy_id" id="proy_id" value="" placeholder="Código del Proyecto" >
    </div>
</div>
```

Me dijeron que colocara un "value", pero no se como llamar eso de la base de datos o como generarlo

este código guarda el proyecto y sus requisitos

```
<?php 
include 'conexion.php'; 
bd_proyecto_agregar($_REQUEST);  
foreach ($_REQUEST['requ'] as $requisito_id){
  $requisito = array('proy_requ_id' => NULL, 'proy_id' => $_REQUEST['proy_id'], 'requ_id' => $requisito_id);
  bd_proyecto_requisito_agregar($requisito);
} 
header("Location: listado2.php"); 
exit; 
?>
```

Comment: Inserta un `0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu función "bd_proyecto_agregar" debe devolver el ID de proyecto que se ha creado automáticamente en mysql, para obtener este ID debes llamar a la funcion   "[mysql_insert_id()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-insert-id.php)" justo despues de hacer el INSERT.

Una vez que devuelvas este ID lo guardas en una variable y la pasas en lugar de pasar "$_REQUEST['proy_id']".

Con lo que el codigo te quedaria como:

```
<?php 
include 'conexion.php'; 
$id = bd_proyecto_agregar($_REQUEST);  
foreach ($_REQUEST['requ'] as $requisito_id){
  $requisito = array('proy_requ_id' => NULL, 'proy_id' => $id, 'requ_id' => $requisito_id);
  bd_proyecto_requisito_agregar($requisito);
} 
header("Location: listado2.php"); 
exit; 
?>
```

Comment: hola, que tal, ya logre modificar el codigo, este automaticamente ya tenia en la funcion de agregar un nuevo proyecto, el codigo para generar el id, ya lo traje hacia el formulario y lo muestra, utilice esta $id = bd_proyecto_agregar($id);  para sustraer la variable ID que esta ya en codigo: $id  = sql2value("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()");

por otro lado en la funcion de agregar el proyecto y agregar sus requisitos: quedo asi 
<?php 
include 'conexion.php'; 

bd_proyecto_agregar($_REQUEST); 
foreach ($_REQUEST['requ'] as $requisito_id){

Comment: $requisito = array('proy_requ_id' => NULL, 'proy_id' => $_REQUEST['proy_id'], 'requ_id' => $requisito_id);
  bd_proyecto_requisito_agregar($requisito);
} 
header("Location: listado2.php"); 
exit; 
?>

no agregue la linea que me dijiste, porque ya lo hago directamente de la otra funcion, creo que asi serviria, el problema, cada vez que se abre el registro de proyectos, la id se autoincrementa (lo que queria) pero si recarga la pagina se autoincrementa de nuevo, ademas de que crea proyectos vacios con solo el id, como puedo solucionar eso

Comment: Que me recomiendas? donde estaria el error

Comment: Tienes que comprobar si request esta vació, si lo esta, antes de insertar redirige de nuevo al listado o al formulario.

Comment: ya lo acomode, e incluso publique de nuevo la pregunta. me da otro error, 
http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22884/agregar-alumnos-a-un-unico-proyecto/22917?noredirect=1#comment36714_22917

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

Creo que aquí hay también una confusión de conceptos, en principio, el ID no deberías modificarlo, en cambio, debería existir un campo ID y uno llamado CODIGO, te recomiendo hacer una modificación a la base de datos, es decir:
 
Definir un campo llamado ID que sea autoincremental y un campo (en este caso proy_id, supongo) en donde se guarde el código de tu proyecto, la idea de un campo AUTOINCREMENT en MySQL es tener una llave que nunca sea modificada, en este caso, un identificador único de tus registros que tengas la seguridad 100% de que no se repetirá en tu tabla porque aumenta automáticamente, por otro lado, en tu campo proy_id que puede ser un varchar(por ejemplo), podrías guardar una nomenclatura diferente, PROY-001-A, PROY-001-B o algo similar.

**¿Cómo hacer la manipulación del registro entonces?**
Sencillo, cuando hagas un INSERT, escribes

> INSERT INTO nombre_tabla ( proy_id,descripcion,etc... ) VALUES (
>   "PROY-001-A", "Este proyecto es sobre",etc... );

Y al ser un INSERT, el campo AUTOINCREMENT se ingresará automáticamente y se quedará listo para el siguiente registro y cuando hagas un UPDATE escribes:

> UPDATE nombre_tabla SET proy_id = "PROY-001-B", descripcion="esta es otra modificacion",etc... WHERE id = $id

En donde **$id** sería un valor que estés enviando en tu $REQUEST (algo como el value que te dijeron que agregaras) que podría verse como

`<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $respuestaBD['id']?>" />`

Y que le inidicaría que registro actualizar, y ¿cómo enviar/llamar el ID? podrías llamar el id como `$id = $_REQUEST['id']` y enviarlo en tu array **$requisito** definido en el código que has publicado.

Espero este planteamiento te sea útil.

Saludos,

Answer (score 0):

Creo que simplemente cuando hagas el `insert` del proyecto en la base de datos, debes omitir el campo de tu ID, entonces MySQL al ver que no hay ningún valor para ese registro auto asignará el correspondiente valor `auto increment` de la columna.

Espero te ayude, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es que el id lo asigne el usuario ( por ejemplo porque viene impreso en un formulario físico ), no debes usar auto increment. Para los documentos asociados en la otra tabla deberias tener dos columnas que forman tu indice
un id ( del documento ) auto inc y un id del proyecto
entonces si ingresas el proyecto 993 en tu tabla de proyectos quedará:

```
id: 99
obs: proyecto ingresado por pepito


en la de documentos:

id: 1023
proyecto_id: 99
documento: planilla excel

id: 1024
proyecto_id: 99
documento: documento pdf
```

y un indice por (proyecto_id, id ) en la segunda tabla te ayudaría a acceder en orden y rapido los documentos del proyecto

```
SELECT * from documentos where proyecto_id=99 order by id
```