# Agregar alumnos a un unico proyecto

Tags: php, mysql

Stackoverflow, saludos, creo esta pregunta porque tengo un sistema que registro de proyectos y los alumnos que lo integran en el, este los guarda en una base de datos, en una tabla anidada PROYECTO_ALUMNO que contiene alumno_id y proyecto_id, como tambien al alumno en un tabla ALUMNO y al proyecto en una tabla PROYECTO.

El problema esta en que tengo un formulario que genera dos selects, uno mostrando los proyectos que existen en la base de datos y otro mostrando en checkbox todos los alumnos que estan en la base de datos, quisiera que se condicionara a los alumnos para que solo aparecieran los que NO estan inscritos, ya que si agrego los alumnos aun proyecto estos vuelven a aparecer para cada uno de los proyectos, y un alumno no podria estar en mas de un proyecto

Trate de solucionar esto con un LEFT JOIN que solo tomara los que su alumno_id no estuviera en la tabla, pero ocurre que los alumnos no se guardan alli directamente, primero creas el proyecto, luego creas los alumnos y luego los inscribes.

NOTA: la tabla de PROYECTO_ALUMNO tiene como llave principal proyecto_alumno_id y como campo UNICO alumno_id

Aqui les dejo los codigos muchas gracias por su ayuda:

1) Funcion que muestra todos los alumnos existentes

```
function bd_alumno_opciones()
{
$sql = "SELECT cedu_alum, CONCAT(cedu_alum,' ',nom1_alum,' ',nom2_alum,' ape1_alum,' ',ape2_alum) FROM alumno ORDER BY cedu_alum ASC";
$res = sql2options( $sql );
return $res;
}
```

2) Funcion sugerida para que solo muestre los que no estan inscritas (el problema ocurre que la tabla de por si estara vacia, como explicaba anteriormente)

```
function bd_alumno_opciones()
{
$sql = "SELECT cedu_alum, CONCAT(cedu_alum,' ',nom1_alum,' ',nom2_alum,' ',ape1_alum,' ',ape2_alum)
FROM alumno LEFT JOIN proyecto_alumno ON cedu_alum = alum_id 
WHERE proy_id = null ORDER BY cedu_alum ASC";
$res = sql2options( $sql );
return $res;
}
```

3) Formulario para inscribir los alumnos sobre la tabla de proyecto_alumno(pro_inscripcion4.php)

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';
foreach ($_REQUEST['alum'] as $alumno_id)
{
$alumno = array('proy_id' => NULL, 'proy_id' => $_REQUEST['proy_id'], 'alum_id' => $alumno_id);
bd_proyecto_alumno_agregar($alumno);
}
header("Location: listado4.php");
exit;
```

4) Codigo que guarda en la tabla Proyecto_alumno

```
function bd_proyecto_alumno_agregar($d)
{
$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO proyecto_alumno (proy_alum_id, proy_id, alum_id)
VALUES ('%s','%s','%s')",
$d['proy_requ_id'],
$d['proy_id'],
$d['alum_id']
);
$res = sql($sql);
$id  = sql2value("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()");
return $id;
}
```

NOTA: El funcionamiento es asi:

El formulario de inscripcion de alumnos hace el llamado al archivo pro_inscripcion4.php

Comment: Más allá del [link de bienvenida](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y [este](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sobre que tener en cuenta al momento de formular preguntas, puede que te interese [este](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) que trata de que hacer al momento de responder.

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda, leere mejor todas las indicaciones para hacer mejor mis preguntas y respuestas, por cierto, no hay una manera de hablar mas directa, estilo chat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu consulta del punto 2) prueba cambiar:

```
WHERE proy_id = null
```

por

```
WHERE proy_id IS null
```

Esto es debido a que el `NULL` en SQL implica que el valor es desconocido, es decir `NULL` no es un valor en sí.

Para evaluar si un campo está `NULL` se hace mediante `IS NULL`. Si querés evaluar que no lo está se utiliza `IS NOT NULL`. Ejemplos de un caso y otro:

Alumnos con nom2_alum en NULL (ojo, el string vacío es un valor).

```
Select alumno_id where nom2_alum is null
```

Alumnos con nom2_alum que no están NULL.

```
Select alumno_id where nom2_alum is not null
```

Comment: Funciona como quiero, solo muestra los que no estan en proyectos, pero ahora pasa algo raro, los proyectos tienen un campo llamado Denominacion, cuando inscribo los alumnos en el proyecto, esta se guarda en blanco, estando antes con el titulo; que podra ser?

creo debe estar fallando el codigo 3

Comment: Te sugiero que abras una pregunta por cada uno de estos temas, sólo pon en cada una de ellas el código relevante.

Comment: esta bien, eso hare, pero porque ocurre lo del problema de que se le borra ese campo de denominacion, alli estan todos los codigos necesarios

Comment: Puede que te interese leer [esto](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y puede que te ayude a mejorar tus preguntas el mirar este [link](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).